# codeigniter login form is not displaying is i post

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my users **controller**

```
function login(){

$data['error']=0;
if($_POST){
        $this->load->model('user');
        $username=$this->input->post('username', true);
        $password=$this->input->post('password', true);

        $type=$this->input->post('user_type', true);
        $user=$this->user->login($username,$password,$type);
        if(!$user){
            $data['error']=1;
                  } else {
            $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user['userID']);
            $this->session->set_userdata('user_type', $user['user_type']);
            redirect(base_url(). 'posts');
                        }
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('login',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
    }
```

this is my user **model**

```
   function login($username,$password){
        $where=array(
            'username'=>$username,
            'password'=>sha1($password),
            'user_type'=>$type
        );
        $this->db->select()->from('users')->where($where);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->first_row('array');
}
```

this is my **view**

```
<?php if($error==1){ ?>
<p>Your Identity is wrong</p>
<?php } ?>
<form action="<?php echo base_url()?>users/login" method="POST">
<p>User Name: <input type="text" name="username" /></p>
<p>Password: <input type="password" name="password" /></p>
<p><input type="submit" value="login" /></p>
</form>
```

not the problem is on the view the (form view'login') is not displaying if i only remove 
the if($_post) from my user controller then it works but is there any place that i have don mistake on my controller of my model or view,

my table is like ('username','password','email','user_type')

regards, in advance for any kind of tips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are loading your view page inside the `if($_POST)` condition. At first, `if($_POST)` is false, the view is not loading.

So, you need to correct it.

Just Use:

```
function login(){

$data['error']=0;

        $this->load->model('user');
        $username=$this->input->post('username', true);
        $password=$this->input->post('password', true);
    $type=$this->input->post('user_type', true);
    $user=$this->user->login($username,$password,$type);
    if(!$user){
        $data['error']=1;
              } else {
        $this->session->set_userdata('userID', $user['userID']);
        $this->session->set_userdata('user_type', $user['user_type']);
        redirect(base_url(). 'posts');
                    }
    $this->load->view('header');
    $this->load->view('login',$data);
    $this->load->view('footer');

}
```

And it will work perfectly.

Comment: now i can see the view but it's showing my error[<p>Your Identity is wrong</p>] with out any kind of action, actuly it's error so after i click login it's must check and let me know and also the login button doesn't do any action....